# Receiving default push notification Firebase Cloud messaging For Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am receiving default push notification instead of my own payload data
in notification.
Here you can see the notification in this Picture below

[image]

I am getting no errors on firebase log, also receiving data which I want to send through push notification
Here you can see
[image]

and here is the code of index.js file of firebase cloud function

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

    exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref(`messages/{notificationId}`).onCreate((event) => {
    const receiverId = event.val().recId;
    const payload = {
        notification: {
        title: `New Message from ${event.val().sndrName}!`,
        body: event.val().message,
        status: "New message",
        icon: 'icon-192x192.png'
        }
    } 
    console.info(payload);
    let tokensList = [];
    return admin.database().ref('fcmtokens').orderByValue().equalTo(receiverId).once('value').then((token) => {
        console.info(token.val());
        if(token.val()) {
            tokensList = (Object.keys(token.val()));
            console.info(tokensList);


            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokensList,payload);
        }
    })

    })
```

I am very new to firebase cloud functions please tell if I am doing something wrong,TIA